# Pass image through props

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-props

I can't seem to pass the image or image url using the props. I want to pass the props from an array to card.

```
import Card from "./Card"


function Specials() {
    const specials = [
        {
            img: '../icons-assets/bruchetta.svg',
            foodItem: 'Bruchetta' ,
            description: 'Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa quis illo at expedita ipsam accusamus, amet libero sit labore quo.',
            price: '$15'
        },
        {
            img: '../icons_assets/greek salad.jpg',
            foodItem: 'Greek Salad' ,
            description: 'Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa quis illo at expedita ipsam accusamus, amet libero sit labore quo.',
            price: '$17.8'
        },
        {
            img: '../icons_assets/lemon dessert.jpg',
            foodItem: 'Lemon Desert' ,
            description: 'Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa quis illo at expedita ipsam accusamus, amet libero sit labore quo.',
            price: '$18.9'
        },
    ]
  return (
    <div className='specials'>
        <div className="special-heading">
            <h1>Specials</h1>
            <button className='btn'>Online Menu</button>
        </div>
        <div className="card-container">
        {specials.map((item,index) => {
            return <Card key={index} image = {item.img} foodItem = {item.foodItem} description = {item.description} price = {item.price} />
        }) }
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Specials
```

I want to pass from here to card component

```
function Card(props) {

  return (
    <>
        <div className="card-content">
            <img src={props.image} alt='picture'/>
            <div className="item-headings" >
                <h3>{props.foodItem}</h3>
                <h4>{props.price}</h4>
            </div>
            <p>{props.description}</p>
        </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Card
```

Everything except the image or path passes through the props. I have tried passing the elements themselves, the path, and the import but none seem to work. And both are in the same folder so path is the same for both.

Comment: What happens with your current code?

Comment: it was a typo in stackoverflow it still doesn't work

Comment: everything passes except the image. the image doesn't show. just the alt

Comment: What's your project directory structure?

Comment: its src as main folder for both components and assests_icon. Inside components is where both specials and card lies. Assests has the image

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your project directory? Maybe the image path is incorrect check once.

Comment: go to network tab in chromedevtools and see the request url of images you are requesting. In nextjs for example all images should be stored in public directory and not next to component

Comment: Path is correct and I went to network tab there was n problem shown but the preview of the image is not shown